# SQL statement with union join or left join

Tags: sql

[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sny3c.png)

I have this SQL problem to find the total count of the disable people between 2 table

The condition is I only want to get the ID with appearing in the recipient table

[left join graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCWeK.png)

I only want to get the total count of the left side data which link together with the a_children

Comment: This is not a complete question.  Please _edit_ your question and include the table data directly as text.  Also show us the expected output, in _table_ form (not as a Venn diagram).

Comment: please visit [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ca178/1

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM recipient r
LEFT JOIN a_children c
ON r.hp_id = c.hp_id
   AND c.health='OKU'
WHERE r.disability = 'YES'
```